# Calculate the following contour integral...

Tags: complex-numbers

Calculate 
$$\oint_\gamma \frac 1{z-\sin z} dz$$ where the contour is the unit circle in the complex plane.

I do not know how to find the order of the pole at 0, though I believe it is 3. Once I have such an order, however, I do not even know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{z-\sin{z}} = \frac{6}{z^3}\frac{1}{1-z^2/20+O(z^4)} = \frac{6}{z^3} \left (1+\frac{z^2}{20}+ O[z^4]\right  ) = \frac{6}{z^3} + \frac{3}{10} \frac{1}{z} + O(z)$$

Thus, the residue at $z=0$ is $3/10$, and the integral is equal to $i 3 \pi/5$.

**EDIT**

$z=0$ is the only pole of the integrand in the unit circle.

Comment: Where does your first equality come from?

Comment: Taylor series for sine: $$\sin{z} = z - \frac16 z^3 + \frac{1}{120} z^5 - \cdots$$

Comment: How did you invert it? What procedure did you use?

Comment: Another Taylor series: $$\frac{1}{1-w} = 1+w + O(w^2)$$

Comment: How do you know that $z = 0$ is the only one ( pole ) inside $\left\vert z\right\vert = 1$ ?

Comment: @FelixMarin: Consider $$\sin{z}-z=i (\cos (x) \sinh (y)-y)+\sin (x) \cosh (y)-x$$  The imaginary part is zero when $\cos (x)=y/\sinh{y}$. Plug this value of $x$ into the real part to get the function $$f(y)=\sin{(\arccos{(y/\sinh{y})})} \cosh{y} - \arccos{(y/\sinh{y})}$$  Plot this function over $y \in (0,1)$ to reveal a zero only at $y=0$.  Thus, $z=0$ is the only zero in the unit disk.